# Worklight 6.1 - Cannot load native page on Android

Tags: android, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

My Worklight application has 2 native pages. One is at the beginning (login) and the other appears after login when a user selects a certain button. Both Native pages are WebViews (Android) the first one works fine, however when I attempt to load the second Native page it doesn't quite work. I see an error:

```
Uncaught Error: A native page is already loaded. Cannot call another native page.
```

in logcat. The Native page partially loads in that my Android ActionBar appears at the top, but the webView content does not load. The first native page calls finish() before I load the 2nd native page. Do I have to explicitly delete or unloaded my first Native page before I can load the second?

I'm using Worklight 6.1. I have a similar implementation for iOS devices and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should explicitly unload the first Native page before you can load the second.